# Is there a way of using an XPages data source (document or view) as a property in a managed bean?

Tags: datasource, javabeans, lotus, lotus-domino, xpages

I would like to have a reference of the actual used data source (eg: com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument) in a managed bean object. Is it possible to have such a property? And how do you implement this approach?

Answer (score 5):

Data source itself is a request scope bean. It is bad idea to keep it as property, I would suggest that your bean's methods accept data source as parameter.
Another approach would be to keep String value of data source name, and get it via JSF binding.